# How to solve the “failed to lazily initialize a collection of role” Hibernate exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, hibernateexception

This is the exception:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: mvc3.model.Topic.comments, no session or session was closed

Here is the model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TOPIC")
public class Topic {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User author;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)    
    private Tag topicTag;

    private String name;
    private String text;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "topic", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Comment> comments = new LinkedHashSet<Comment>();

    ...

    public Collection<Comment> getComments() {
           return comments;
    }

}
```

The controller, which calls model looks like the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/topic")
public class TopicController {

    @Autowired
    private TopicService service;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicController.class);
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/details/{topicId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView details(@PathVariable(value="topicId") int id) {
    
        Topic topicById = service.findTopicByID(id);
        Collection<Comment> commentList = topicById.getComments();
    
        Hashtable modelData = new Hashtable();
        modelData.put("topic", topicById);
        modelData.put("commentList", commentList);
    
        return new ModelAndView("/topic/details", modelData);       
     }
}
```

The jsp-page looks li the following:

```
<%@page import="com.epam.mvc3.helpers.Utils"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>View Topic</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach items="${commentList}" var="item">
                <jsp:useBean id="item" type="mvc3.model.Comment"/>
                <li>${item.getText()}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The exception is raised when viewing the jsp. In the line with *c:forEach* loop

Answer (score 249, accepted):

If you know that you'll want to see all `Comment`s every time you retrieve a `Topic` then change your field mapping for `comments` to:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "topic", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Comment> comments = new LinkedHashSet<Comment>();
```

Collections are lazy-loaded by default, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence) if you want to know more.

Comment: Sorry, but i'd like to use lazy-load. So, I've changed the 'LinkedHashSet' type t the 'PersistentList'.  Exception still occurs

Comment: I've changed my mind. It works nice for the well-mapped tutorial project. Thanks )

Comment: This could be used as a workaround, but not an actual solution to the problem. What if we need to fetch lazily?

Comment: Is it possible to load them lazy, without that Exception?

Comment: but in case if we want lazy then this solution will not work and most of the cases we want lazy only.

Comment: @prashantthakre clearly it won't work if you want lazy-loading, the whole point of this answer is that it loads the objects eagerly

Comment: @darrengorman Thanks but such fix for ManyToMany to give error - 'Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags'

Comment: This is the type of answer that pops up everywhere on stack overflow. Short, to the point, solves the problem and MISLEADING. To future readers, do yourself a favor and learn what exactly is lazy and eagerly fetched, and understand the consequences.

Comment: @Ced in what way does the answer mislead? It clearly states that this is only a solution *if* the collection is to be loaded every time. Initially the OP stated they'd like to lazily fetch, but then changed their mind and accepted the answer. The answer even links to a concise explanation of the differences between the two strategies. I provided a possible solution, but never claimed it was the only one.

Comment: @darrengorman  When I started JPA I posted a question around the lines of OP's one. I received the same response as you gave. Soon enough when I ran some test with hundreds of thousands of row, guess what happened ? I think it is misleading because it provides too simple of an answer for a problem that mostly beginners will face and soon enough they will have their whole database loaded in memory if they are not careful (and they won't, because they won't be aware of it) :).

Comment: Loading with eager may return duplicate result due to join query, To avoid this add @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)

Comment: In my case, the "fetch = FetchType.EAGER" was enouth.

Comment: Setting @JsonIgnore annotation do the job for me.

Comment: This isn't actually a solution to the question, it's just changing to use eager loading, which might not actually be appropriate in many cases.

Comment: The solution is not correct. We need lazy loading most of the time. It will never cover all scenarios.

Comment: How can i solve this with out changing fetch type to EAGER

Comment: How is this the top/accepted answer? Clearly people come to this to find out how to solve the lazy load exception. The solution isn't to switch to use eager loading...

Comment: Difference between FetchType LAZY and EAGER?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence-api

Comment: This shoudnt be accepted since it's misleading. Suggest enabling EAGER load without further thinking could create big other problems in the future. Is a crappy solution.

Comment: @Rafael doing anything in software development without further thinking could create problems in the future. 7.5 years after I answered this question your comment doesn't add any value.

Comment: Wonder why this got so many likes. It removes the exception, but there is a VERY GOOD reason for why FeatchType.LAZY is the default value for @OneToMany.
With this reply, you could just as well UN-invent FetchType.LAZY

Answer (score 219):

From my experience, I have the following methods to solve the famous `LazyInitializationException`:

**(1) Use Hibernate.initialize**

```
Hibernate.initialize(topics.getComments());
```

**(2) Use JOIN FETCH**

You can use the `JOIN FETCH` syntax in your JPQL to explicitly fetch the child collection out. This is somehow like `EAGER` fetching.

**(3) Use OpenSessionInViewFilter**

`LazyInitializationException` often occurs in the view layer. If you use Spring framework, you can use `OpenSessionInViewFilter`. However, I do not suggest you to do so. It may lead to performance issues if not used correctly.

Comment: (1) worked for me perfectly. My case: Hibernate.initialize(registry.getVehicle().getOwner().getPerson().getAddress());

Comment: It seems that Hibernate.initialize doesn't work with EntityManager

Comment: This should be the correct answer. For example in my project at work we are explicitly not supposed to use EAGER fetching. It causes problems in this particular system.

Comment: Seems attractive but lack of documentation to implement in another case... could you please provide some more links or explanation on how to implement this solution?

Answer (score 127):

I know it's an old question but I want to help.
You can put the transactional annotation on the service method you need, in this case findTopicByID(id) should have

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true, noRollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

more info about this annotation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740021/transactionalpropagation-propagation-required)

About the other solutions:

```
fetch = FetchType.EAGER
```

is not a good practice, it should be used ONLY if necessary.

```
Hibernate.initialize(topics.getComments());
```

The hibernate initializer binds your classes to the hibernate technology. If you are aiming to be flexible is not a good way to go.

Hope it helps

Comment: The @Transactional annotation worked for me, but note that Propagation.REQUIRED is the default, at least in Spring Boot 1.4.2 (Spring 4.3).

Comment: Yes it is, but I thought it could be appreciated to make it clear you could actually change the propagation param

Comment: Isn't `@Transactional` a Spring-only thing?

Comment: @Campa yes it is. If you want to handle it manually you should put your business logic inside a transaction retrieved from the entity manager

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this fixes my problem, but it did. Thank you!

Comment: Putting `@Transactional` on the getter of the collection was the fix for me. It's clean and makes sense, but it had to be done in the Entity class, which I am not really a fan of but better than not having it work.

Comment: is FetchType.EAGER a good practice in @OneToMany decorators?

Comment: @fer.trecool no it isn't. It's really demanding in terms of performance and you can obtain the same result lazily with the solution proposed in my answer. I think the only scenario of use would be a static small dataset that is really needed at every call BUT if you used Transactional correctly you would be covered anyway so..no

Answer (score 74):

### The origin of your problem:

By default hibernate lazily loads the collections (relationships) which means whenver you use the `collection` in your code(here `comments` field
in `Topic` class)
the hibernate gets that from database, now the problem is that you are getting the collection in your controller (where the 
JPA session is closed).This is the line of code that causes the exception
(where you are loading the `comments` collection):

```
    Collection<Comment> commentList = topicById.getComments();
```

You are  getting "comments" collection (topic.getComments()) in your controller(where `JPA session` has ended) and that causes the exception. Also if you had got 
the `comments` collection in your jsp file like this(instead of getting it in your controller):

```
<c:forEach items="topic.comments" var="item">
//some code
</c:forEach>
```

You would still have the same exception for the same reason.

### Solving the problem:

Because you just can have only two collections with the `FetchType.Eager`(eagerly fetched collection) in an Entity class and because lazy loading is more
efficient than eagerly loading, I think this way of solving your problem is better than just changing the `FetchType` to eager:

If you want to have collection lazy initialized, and also make this work,
it is better to add this snippet of code to your `web.xml` :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

What this code does is that it will increase the length of your `JPA session` or as the documentation says, it is used `"to allow for lazy loading in web views despite the original transactions already being completed."` so 
this way the JPA session will be open a bit longer and because of that
you can lazily load collections in your jsp files and controller classes.

Comment: Why is JPS session closed? How to make it not being closed? How to perform lazy collection?

Comment: What defines a limit of two FetchType.Eager collections per Entity?

Comment: In Spring Boot, you can add 'spring.jpa.open-in-view=true' to 'application.properties'

Comment: @Askar My project is based on Spring Boot and your soulution doesn't work

Comment: ... Spring Boot version 2.2.4

Comment: ... and it seems to be an antipattern - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222934/1353723

Comment: @0xC0DEGURU Thanks for your consideration, I will take that in account and investigate. This solution worked for me few years ago and I've forgot the details. Also thanks for the provided link.

Answer (score 45):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/topic")
@Transactional
```

I solved this problem by adding `@Transactional`, I think this can open a session.

Comment: Why did this receive a minus vote? Adding a transaction to the operation extends the session

Comment: It is bad practice to ad @Transactional to the controller.

Comment: @Rafael Why it's a bad practice?

Comment: @AmrEllafy -> Here it is a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498834/1261162

Comment: @Rafael, it's bad practice to use the opinion of one person and say it is bad practice. If you pointed to a recommendation from the people at Spring fine, but in this case you pointed to a SO answer that wasn't even accepted and makes no reference to official Spring documentation.

Comment: @JeSuisAlrick This entire site is based on professional advice. It is my professional advice to avoid the proposed solution and consider it as a bad practice, and I pointed to a very clear explanation of why. Anyone can of course disagree with that. If you don't want to accept that explanation because it doesn't comes from Spring, that's your decision. Others may or may not agree with you. But I must vote minus because I really think that's a misleading answer.

Comment: @Rafael, I understand what you and the SO answer you referred to are saying. But my question is, if the transaction needs to extend to the controller for the lazy loading of related models, how is a transaction not a cross-cutting concern in this case? If a transaction does address cross-cutting concerns, then how is this approach bad practice? Isn't it subjective and based on the specific implementation of transaction management? If this answer is bad practice, what would be your alternative answer for this SO?

Comment: @JeSuisAlrick "if the transaction needs to extend to the controller for the lazy loading of related models". Thats an opinionated design decision ... which IMO is wrong. You shouldn't extend the transaction boundary up to the controller. If you are refering to "Open Session In View" ... that's an anti-pattern to me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103363/why-is-hibernate-open-session-in-view-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @Rafael, I see what you mean--"finalise" the resulting DTO at the service layer and pass that on to the presentation layer. I'm guessing that if he was using MapStruct he'd move it to the service layer and resolve the DTO(s) using it. A sound solution.

Answer (score 43):

The best way to handle the [`LazyInitializationException`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/) is to [join fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468551/4982691) upon query time, like this:

```
select t
from Topic t
left join fetch t.comments
```

You should ALWAYS avoid the following anti-patterns:

- `FetchType.EAGER`
- [OSIV (Open Session in View)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37526397/1025118)
- [`hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` Hibernate configuration property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39723223/1025118)

Therefore, make sure that your `FetchType.LAZY` associations are initialized at query time or within the original `@Transactional` scope using `Hibernate.initialize` for secondary collections.

Comment: Vlad do you have any suggestions for working with a lazy-initialized collection in an entity fetched by a Spring-generated repository's findById() method? I'm not writing the query and the transaction is outside my code.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'within the original @Transactional scope' This is unclear to me as I seem to get this error while in an open session (but not the right one?)

Comment: While inside the scope o the top-most transactional service method, also known as the transaction gateway. Check out the `TrassctionInterceptor` in the stack trace and that's the one.

Comment: One of the best answers by far ... this should marked as the correct.
BTW ... assuming OSIV is an anti-pattern how is possible that is enabled by default on spring-boot recent versions? ... maybe is not that bad?

Comment: Of course, it's bad. Starting with Spring Boot 2, [a warning is logged telling you to disable it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7107).

Comment: I just want to say, I found this answer and Vlad's article to be very helpful. I did resolve my issue without resorting to eager loading, OSIV or enable_lazy_load_no_trans. I am sure those things exist for a reason and there are valid use cases, but I have yet to encounter one. For me, it was as simple as making the service layer @Transactional, which is exactly what this answer's last lines say.

Answer (score 36):

The problem is caused by accessing an attribute with the hibernate session closed. You have not a hibernate transaction in the controller.

Possible solutions:

1. **Do all this logic, in the service layer**, (with the @Transactional), not in the controller. There should be the right place to do this, it is part of the logic of the app, not in the controller (in this case, an interface to load the model). All the operations in the service layer should be transactional.
   i.e.: Move this line to the TopicService.findTopicByID method:

   Collection commentList = topicById.getComments();
2. **Use 'eager' instead of 'lazy'**. Now you are not using 'lazy' .. it is not a real solution, if you want to use lazy, works like a temporary (very temporary) workaround.
3. **use @Transactional in the Controller**. It should not be used here, you are mixing service layer with presentation, it is not a good design.
4. **use OpenSessionInViewFilter**, many disadvantages reported, possible instability.

**In general, the best solution is the 1.**

Comment: Fetch type of Eager assumed that hibernate will be pulled all data in the first query, not all places it is correctly

Comment: You should UPPERCASE that the BEST SOLUTION IS 1 ... in fact is the ONLY GOOD solution since all others are anti-patterns!

Comment: I agree with @Rafael the only solution is the first

Answer (score 29):

The reason is that when you use lazy load, the session is closed.

There are two solutions.

1. Don't use lazy load.

   Set `lazy=false` in XML or Set `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` In annotation.
2. Use lazy load.

   Set `lazy=true` in XML or Set `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` In annotation.

   and add `OpenSessionInViewFilter filter` in your `web.xml`

Detail See my [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286187/1808417).

Comment: ... and yet both solutions are not good. Suggest using EAGER can create huge problems. Using OpenSessionInViewFilter is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 20):

In order to lazy load a collection there must be an active session.  In a web app there are two ways to do this.  You can use the [Open Session In View](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView?_sscc=t) pattern, where you use an [interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html) to open the session at the beginning of the request and close it at the end.  The risk there is that you have to have solid exception handling or you could bind up all your sessions and your app could hang.

The other way to handle this is to collect all the data you need in your controller, close your session, and then stuff the data into your model.  I personally prefer this approach, as it seems a little closer to the spirit of the MVC pattern.  Also if you get an error from the database this way you can handle it a lot better than if it happens in your view renderer.  Your friend in this scenario is [Hibernate.initialize](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization)(myTopic.getComments()).  You will also have to reattach the object to the session, since you're creating a new transaction with every request.  Use session.lock(myTopic,LockMode.NONE) for that.

Answer (score 17):

One of the best solutions is to add the following in your application.properties file:
**spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true**

Comment: Can you tell the OP what it does exactly, any side effects, performance impact?

Comment: At the back of the lazy loading, a new session is forked every time an association is loaded lazily, hence more connections are forked and creates a bit of pressure on the connection pool. If you have a limit on the number of connections then this property might not be a correct one to use.

Comment: for some, it is considered as an anti-pattern
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hibernate-enable_lazy_load_no_trans-anti-pattern/

Answer (score 14):

I got this error after a second execution of a method to generate a JWT token.

The line *user.getUsersRole().stream().forEachOrdered((ur) -> roles.add(ur.getRoleId()));* generated the error.

```java
// MyUserDetails.java

@Service
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {

    /* ERROR
    /* org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to 
    /* lazily initialize a collection of role: 
    /* com.organizator.backend.model.User.usersRole, 
    /* could not initialize proxy - no Session */
    user.getUsersRole().stream().forEachOrdered((ur) ->
           roles.add(ur.getRoleId()));
```

In my case the `@Transactional` annotation solved it,

```java
// MyUserDetails.java

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

  @Override
  @Transactional // <-- added
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {

    /* No Error */
    user.getUsersRole().stream().forEachOrdered((ur) ->
           roles.add(ur.getRoleId()));
```

Comment: Could you pls tell why @Transactional solved this issue?

Answer (score 12):

If you are trying to have a relation between a entity and a Collection or a List of java objects (for example Long type), it would like something like this:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Long> ids;
```

Comment: in many cases, you really don't want to do that. You loose all the benefits of lazy loading here

Answer (score 11):

Two things you should have for `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`.

```
@Transactional
```

and

```
Hibernate.initialize(topicById.getComments());
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro. I exactly found second block :)

Answer (score 9):

@Transactional annotation on controller is missing

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@Transactional
public class UserController {
}
```

Comment: I would argue that transaction management belongs to service layer where the business logic resides.

Comment: Transactional annotation is not missing. Controller should not have such annotation. Those annotations should be at Service level.

Comment: Since I didn't want to set `FetchMode` to `EAGER`, this was my solution.

Comment: There are some cases where the intial entity need to be reload in the controller and then pass it the @Transactional at the controller level is the workaround I've used, it is far better from changing to eager. JPA doesn't have proper solution for this one. This annotation is used for a specific end-point in the contrller whereas changing to EAGER affect all calls!

Comment: There are some cases where the intial entity need to be reload in the controller. @Transactional at the controller level is the workaround I've used, but after reading the comments I move the annoation to the service layer. What I did is reload the entity again in the service layer. So two benefits, change to EAGER is not required and annotation is in the right place. The only probelm is unnessary query is done.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple solution for this Lazy Initialisation issue -

1) Change the association Fetch type from LAZY to EAGER but this is not a good practice because this will degrade the performance.

2) Use FetchType.LAZY on associated Object and also use Transactional annotation in your service layer method so that session will remain open and when you will call topicById.getComments(), child object(comments) will get loaded.

3) Also, please try to use DTO object instead of entity in controller layer. In your case, session is closed at controller layer. SO better to convert entity to DTO in service layer.

Answer (score 7):

I found out that declaring `@PersistenceContext` as `EXTENDED` also solves this problem:

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
```

Comment: Hi, be careful with such changes. TRANSACTION scoped persistence context creation is lazy, which was the OP intent. So the question is whether you want to be stateless or not. This setting is dependent on the purpose of the system and shouldn't be changed too... eagerly. If you know what I mean. Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547817/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-scoped-persistence-context-and-extend

Comment: Dangerous. This is not the correct answer. There are others above much more accurate and safe.

Answer (score 7):

To solve the problem in my case it was just missing this line

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />
```

in the application-context file.

The `@Transactional` annotation over a method was not taken into account.

Hope the answer will help someone

Answer (score 7):

The problem is caused because the code is accessing a lazy JPA relation when the "connection" to the database is closed (*persistence context* is the correct name in terms of Hibernate/JPA).

A simple way of solving it in Spring Boot is by defining a service layer and using the `@Transactional` annotation. This annotation in a method creates a transaction that propagates into the repository layer and keeps open the persistence context until the method finish. If you access the collection inside the transactional method Hibernate/JPA will fetch the data from the database.

In your case, you just need to annotate with `@Transactional` the method `findTopicByID(id)` in your `TopicService` and force the fetch of the collection in that method (for instance, by asking its size):

```java
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Topic findTopicById(Long id) {
        Topic topic = TopicRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        topic.getComments().size();
        return topic;
    }
```

Comment: annotating a service method with `@Transactional` is not a good practice. It just blocks the connection to your db. This will cause your app to become unresponsive when the method calls increase.

Comment: The use of `@Transctional` annotation in services is documented in multiple tutorials like https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-transactional-annotation/ or in the official Spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings

Comment: We had used this on the methods that called our database (repository). After an increase in the number of method calls, our app started to hang. This was because this annotation blocks the current database connection. We had 30 Hikaripool database connections. All would exceed. Guess what! we removed these annotations from our service layer methods and added them to the repository.  
If you want to replicate the issue, you could try to configure something above. We used spring boot by the way.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, it is very useful. I'll investigate your solution.

Answer (score 6):

your list is lazy loading, so the list wasn't loaded.
call to get on the list is not enough.
use in Hibernate.initialize in order to init the list.
If dosnt work run on the list element and call Hibernate.initialize for each .
this need to be before you return from the transaction scope.
look at [this](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20533.html) post.
search for  -

```
Node n = // .. get the node
Hibernate.initialize(n); // initializes 'parent' similar to getParent.
Hibernate.initialize(n.getChildren()); // pass the lazy collection into the session
```

Answer (score 5):

it was the problem i recently faced which i solved with using

```
<f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.ArrayList" />
```

more detailed decription [here](http://blog.itcrowd.pl/2013/02/jsf-manytomany-and-lazyinitializationex.html) and this saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

*This is an old question but the below information may help people looking for an answer to this.*

@VladMihalcea 's answer is useful. You must not rely on `FetchType.EAGER` , instead you should load the comments into the `Topic` entity when required.

If you are not explicitly defining your queries so that you could specify a `join fetch`, then using `@NamedEntityGraph` and `@EntityGraph` **you could override** the `FetchType.LAZY` (`@OneToMany` associations use LAZY by default) **at runtime** and load the comments at the same time as the `Topic` **only when required**. Which means that you restrict loading the comments to only those methods (queries) which really require that. An entity graph as JPA [defines](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) it:

> An entity graph can be used with the find method or as a query hint to
> override or augment FetchType semantics.

You could use it based on the JPA example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph). Alternatively, if you use Spring Data JPA, then you could use it based on the example [provided by Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph).

Answer (score 4):

By using the hibernate `@Transactional` annotation, if you get an object from the database with lazy fetched attributes, you can simply get these by fetching these attributes like this :

```
@Transactional
public void checkTicketSalePresence(UUID ticketUuid, UUID saleUuid) {
        Optional<Ticket> savedTicketOpt = ticketRepository.findById(ticketUuid);
        savedTicketOpt.ifPresent(ticket -> {
            Optional<Sale> saleOpt = ticket.getSales().stream().filter(sale -> sale.getUuid() == saleUuid).findFirst();
            assertThat(saleOpt).isPresent();
        });
}
```

Here, in an Hibernate proxy-managed transaction, the fact of calling `ticket.getSales()` do another query to fetch sales because you explicitly asked it.

Answer (score 4):

To get rid of lazy initialization exception you should not call for lazy collection when you operate with detached object.

From my opinion, best approach is to use DTO, and not entity. In this case you can explicitly set fields which you want to use. As usual it's enough. No need to worry that something like jackson `ObjectMapper`, or `hashCode` generated by Lombok will call your methods implicitly.

For some specific cases you can use `@EntityGrpaph` annotation, which allow you to make `eager` load even if you have `fetchType=lazy` in your entity.

Answer (score 2):

For those working with [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html), I found that

```
criteria.setFetchMode("lazily_fetched_member", FetchMode.EAGER);
```

did everything I needed had done.

Initial fetch mode for collections is set to FetchMode.LAZY to provide performance, but when I need the data, I just add that line and enjoy the fully populated objects.

Answer (score 2):

In my case following code was a problem:

```
entityManager.detach(topicById);
topicById.getComments() // exception thrown
```

Because it detached from the database and Hibernate no longer retrieved list from the field when it was needed. So I initialize it before detaching:

```
Hibernate.initialize(topicById.getComments());
entityManager.detach(topicById);
topicById.getComments() // works like a charm
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had the mapping b/w `A` and `B` like

`A` has

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Set<B> bs;
```

in the `DAO` layer, the **method** needs to be annotated with `@Transactional` if you haven't annotated the mapping with **Fetch Type - Eager**

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution, but for those who are facing `LazyInitializationException` especially on `Serialization` this will help. Here you will check lazily initialized properties and setting `null` to those. For that create the below class

```
public class RepositoryUtil {
    public static final boolean isCollectionInitialized(Collection<?> collection) {
        if (collection instanceof PersistentCollection)
            return ((PersistentCollection) collection).wasInitialized();
        else 
            return true;
    }   
}
```

Inside your Entity class which you are having lazily initialized properties add a method like shown below. Add all your lazily loading properties inside this method.

```
public void checkLazyIntialzation() {
    if (!RepositoryUtil.isCollectionInitialized(yourlazyproperty)) {
        yourlazyproperty= null;
    }
```

Call this `checkLazyIntialzation()` method after on all the places where you are loading data.

```
 YourEntity obj= entityManager.find(YourEntity.class,1L);
  obj.checkLazyIntialzation();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are trying to get the commentList on your controller after closing the session inside the service.

```
topicById.getComments();
```

Above will load the commentList only if your hibernate session is active, which I guess you closed in your service.

**So, you have to get the commentList before closing the session.**

Comment: Yes, this is the problem statement, You should also provide an answer in an `Answer`

Answer (score 1):

The collection `comments` in your model class `Topic` is lazily loaded, which is the default behaviour if you don't annotate it with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` specifically.

It is mostly likely that your `findTopicByID` service is using a stateless Hibernate session. [A stateless session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html) does not have the first level cache, i.e., no persistence context. Later on when you try to iterate `comments`, Hibernate will throw an exception.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: mvc3.model.Topic.comments, no session or session was closed
```

The solution can be:

1. Annotate `comments` with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`

   ```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "topic", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)   
   private Collection<Comment> comments = new LinkedHashSet<Comment>();
   ```
2. If you still would like comments to be lazily loaded, use [Hibernate's stateful sessions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html), so that you'll be able to fetch comments later on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Hi All posting quite late hope it helps others,
Thanking in advance to @GMK for this post  [Hibernate.initialize(object)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization)

when Lazy="true"

```
Set<myObject> set=null;
hibernateSession.open
set=hibernateSession.getMyObjects();
hibernateSession.close();
```

now if i access 'set' after closing session it throws exception.

My solution :

```
Set<myObject> set=new HashSet<myObject>();
hibernateSession.open
set.addAll(hibernateSession.getMyObjects());
hibernateSession.close();
```

now i can access 'set' even after closing Hibernate Session.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do the thing, you can use [TransactionTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch11s06.html) to wrap around the lazy fetch.
Like

```
Collection<Comment> commentList = this.transactionTemplate.execute
(status -> topicById.getComments());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was passing a detached entity to a component (even annotated with @Transactional) within a test case. So after reloading the entity it worked:

```
@Entity
class Entity {
   @ElementCollection
   @BatchSize(size = 10)
   private List<String> strings;
}

@Component
@Transactional
class MyTestComponent {

   public String method(Entity detachedEntity) {
      // reloading the entity fixed it
      Entity entity = entityRepository.findById(detachedEntity.getId());
      // detachedEntity.getStrings(); caused the problem
      entity.getStrings(); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in a spring boot integration test while trying to log the result of a JPA repository `findAll()`. Adding `@Transactional` to the test method fixed it.

`log.debug("entities {}", userRepository.findAll());`

Answer (score -1):

In my Spring-Boot project `spring.jpa.open-in-view` was set to false in application.properties. Setting it to true solved the problem.