# NullPointerException when want to access lazy loaded collection in jUnit test

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, many-to-one

In my Spring app i have Two entity:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;
      ....
  @OneToOne
  @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name="page_id")
  private Page page;

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="category")
  private List<Shop> shop;

      ..getters and setters
 }
```

And

```
  @Entity
  public class Shop {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;
      ....

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="shop")
  private Settings settings;


  @ManyToOne
  @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
  private Category category;

  @OneToOne
  @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name = "page_id")
  private Page page;
      ...getters and setters
```

}

And in my test jUnit i added some category and some shop with this category, when i want to access to list of shops current category i have a error 
    java.lang.NullPointerException ....

My test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:security-context.xml",
    "classpath:dao-context.xml"
})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional
public class CategoryTest { 

Shop shop1 = new Shop(....);
Shop shop1 = new Shop(....);
Category category1 = new Category(....);
Category category2 = new Category(....);

@Test
public void someTest(){
    shop1.setCategory(category1);
    shop2.setCategory(category2);
    shopService.add(shop1);
    shopService.add(shop2);
    assertEquals(2, shopService.getAllShop().size());
    assertEquals(2, categoryService.getAllShop().size());
      //IN THIS LINE I HAVE A ERROR
    assertEquals(1, categoryService.getCategory(category1.getId()).getShop().size());
   }
 }
```

For access to lazy atribute i added to my web.xml filtr: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter This working properly in front app not in jUnit test.
Which point I make an error?

Answer (score 0):

The lazy loading only takes place whist inside a transaction, when the session is open. So you get null in the test method unless you initialize the lazy loaded collection beforehand.

[Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13671178/106261)

Comment: I know that so i added org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter to my web.xml and added @Transactional annotation to my test class. But this not help.  Am i wrong?