# Spring error "Bean named 'x' is expected to be of type 'y', but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy]"

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am trying to implement a DAO based authentication in an application using Spring Security.

When I tried to log in to the application with a user I got this error:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.app.dao.User.groups, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Looking at @jcmwright80 's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821695/how-to-fix-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a) I understood that I should ideally annotate `UserDetailsServiceImpl` class as `@Transactional`. After doing that I got an error during login:

```
Bean named 'userDetailsService' is expected to be of type 'com.example.app.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy238'"}}
```

**This seems to be an issue related to the proxy object created on UserDetailsServiceImpl - how can I fix this gracefully?**

**CODE**

Relevant part of the security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.app.service")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl () {};
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
        User user = userDao.getUser(username);
        
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException ("User not found.");
        }
        return new UserDetailsImpl(user);
    }
  }
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users",schema="sec")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="userGen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="userGen", sequenceName="user_id_seq", schema="sec")
    private long id;    

    // Validation constraints on the fields ...
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="group_members", schema="sec", joinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name="user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="group_id") } )
    private Set<Group> groups;

 // Getters, Setters etc. ...
 }
```

(The alternative solution of using `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` on collection type fields in `User` and `Group` classes works, though it could impact performance.)

Comment: I think there is a problem in your code: You have `@Bean UserDetailsService userDetailsService()` vs. `@Service("userDetailsService") class UserDetailsServiceImpl`. It looks like there are two identically named ways to instantiate the service bean with two different types. The `@Bean` has the interface type and this is what gets created as a JDK proxy. In another place you explicitly declare the `@Service` to have an implementation type, which contradicts the bean factory method. I think you need to fix this inconsistency because it causes your problem, as the error message indicates.

Comment: @kriegaex Indeed this could be related to the problem. When I changed the return type of the `@Bean` to `UserDetailsServiceImpl` in `SecurityConfig` then it gave a clearer description of the error:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method SecurityConfig.userDetailsService called as bean reference for type [com.intellivest.app.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy330].`
Spring advises that
> "JDK dynamic proxies are preferred whenever you have a choice"
What solution do you propose keeping that in mind?

Comment: I am not a Spring user. But basically either you have to make sure everything is referenced to and instantiated as the interface type when using JDK proxies, which is the type created somewhere in your application as can be seen from the class name `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy330`. Maybe it is enough to add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to your configuration class. Alternatively, you could enforce usage of CGLIB proxies via `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)`. I am too busy to copy all your classes into a new project and play around, if you have a GitHub project for me I can take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1 (Optimal)**

The methods used in the `@Service` class should all be declared in an interface that the `@Service` implements. Then the service can be referred to via its interface type everywhere (e.g. in `@Controller` class). This way Spring can continue to use JDK dynamic proxies (which are preferred over CGLIB).

This was especially important as an interface provided by Spring was implemented: `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` which declared only 1 method but others were required too.
This was rather a design problem than a simple coding issue.

Step by step:

```
public interface CustomizedUserDetailsService extends UserDetailsService {
    void add(User user);
}
```

Implement the methods in the service:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements CustomizedUserDetailsService{
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void add (User user) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Reference the bean through its interface type in the `@Configuration` **but return the implementation**:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public CustomizedUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
}
```

While using the implementation inject the bean through a reference to its implemented interface:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    private CustomizedUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    public void setUsersService(CustomizedUserDetailsService customizedUserDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = customizedUserDetailsService;
    }
}
```

More details on proxies [here](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring).

**Solution 2**

Use an annotation to enable CGLIB proxy on the service class.
This required spring-aop and aspectjweaver dependencies (not using Spring Boot).

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
```

Then the security configuration class can produce the bean like this:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
}
```

(The DAO layer should not be `@Transactional`, that should only be applied to the `@Service` class or specific methods of the latter class.)