# Bean named 'documentProcessorApiService' is expected to be of type 'DocumentProcessorApiService' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, runtime-error, autowired

I have been battling this problem for a few days, using other suggestions I've found to no avail.   I've tried using @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) on the SpringApplication entry and the Configuration classes.   I have spring.aop.auto.true and spring.aop.proxy-target-class.true in my application yml file and still the same error.   I have tried setting it as an interface with no luck as well.  I have this as the Component that is being complained about

```
@Component
@EnableRetry
@Slf4j
public class DocumentProcessorApiService {
    private final RestTemplate documentsApiRestTemplate;
    private final DocumentsApiProperties documentsApiProperties;
    private final MulesoftProperties mulesoftProperties;
    private static final String DOCUMENT_SEARCH_PATH = "/documents/_search";
    private static final String PROPS_NAME_VALUE_MAP_FIELD = "propsNameValueMap";
    private static final String DOCUMENT_TYPE_FIELD = "Document Type";
    private static final String UW_ERROR_REPORT_TYPE = "UW ERROR RPT";
    @Autowired
    public DocumentProcessorApiService(@Qualifier("documentsApiRestTemplate") RestTemplate documentsApiRestTemplate, DocumentsApiProperties documentsApiProperties,
                                       MulesoftProperties mulesoftProperties) {
        this.documentsApiRestTemplate = documentsApiRestTemplate;
        this.documentsApiProperties = documentsApiProperties;
        this.mulesoftProperties = mulesoftProperties;
    }
```

and this is what is using it as Autowired as well

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class LifeWorkflowEventListener {

    private final EventConverter eventConverter;
    private final JmsService jmsService;
    private final DocumentProcessorApiService documentProcessorApiService;
    private final LifeApplicationService lifeApplicationService;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.workflow-event.action-event-type:}")
    String actionEventType;

    @Autowired
    public LifeWorkflowEventListener(@Qualifier("lifeWorkflow") EventConverter eventConverter,
                                     JmsService jmsService,
                                     DocumentProcessorApiService documentProcessorApiService,
                                     LifeApplicationService lifeApplicationService) {
        this.eventConverter = eventConverter;
        this.jmsService = jmsService;
        log.info("documentProcessorApiService {}", documentProcessorApiService.toString());
        this.documentProcessorApiService = documentProcessorApiService;
        this.lifeApplicationService = lifeApplicationService;
    }
```

I appreciate any ideas I have not tried yet, or letting me know if I'm doing something else wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Spring thinks that it has to wrap methods in `DocumentProcessorApiService`, for example, to handle transactions. In order to do that, it creates a proxy. If you have an interface, Spring can make the proxy return `true` when it's asked "are you assignment compatible with type XYZ".

Steps to fix:

1. Rename `DocumentProcessorApiService` to `DocumentProcessorApiServiceImpl`. Rename the file manually and fix the compile error instead of refactoring; see below.
2. Create an interface `DocumentProcessorApiService`
3. Make `DocumentProcessorApiServiceImpl` implement that interface
4. If you used refactoring for the rename, replace `DocumentProcessorApiServiceImpl` everywhere with `DocumentProcessorApiService` except for the name of the class itself.
5. Add an entry in a `@Configuration` bean to let Spring know how to create `DocumentProcessorApiService`

This works. If it doesn't, then there must be a mistake elsewhere. In this case, ask a new question with the changed code and the exact error message.

See also: [Spring error "Bean named 'x' is expected to be of type 'y', but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65235534/spring-error-bean-named-x-is-expected-to-be-of-type-y-but-was-actually-of)