# how to Resolve "could not initialize proxy - no session" error when using Spring repository

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, microservices, multi-tenant

I'm working on a mutitenant project it maintains different schema for each tenant, followed [Project](https://dzone.com/articles/dynamic-multi-tenancy-using-java-spring-boot-sprin)

As we are dynamically switching the tenants so it looks like some configuration is missed which is **closing the session or not keeping the session open to fetch the LAZY loaded objects**. Which results in "could not initialize proxy - no session" error.

Please check below link to access the complete project and db schema scripts, please follow the steps given in Readme file.
[Project](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i-KspfPT650FNdF4jRuypzHwPCsUmYEB)

It will be helpful if someone can point out the issue in the code.

i tried to put service methods in @Transactional annotation but that didn't work.

I'm expecting it to make another call to the LAZY loaded object, This project is simplefied verson of the complex project, actually i have lot more lazy loaded objects.

Issue:-
I'm getting no Session error "could not initialize proxy [com.amran.dynamic.multitenant.tenant.entity.Tenant#1] - no Session"
at line 26 (/dynamicmultitenant/src/main/java/com/amran/dynamic/multitenant/tenant/service/ProductServiceImpl.java)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Hibernate LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821695/how-to-fix-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your transaction boundaries are not correct. In `TenantDatabaseConfig` and `MasterDatabaseConfig` you've correctly added `@EnableTransactionManagement`, which will setup transactions when requested.

However - the outermost component that has an (implicit) `@Transactional` annotation is the `ProductRepository` (by virtue of it being implemented by the `SimpleJpaRepository` class - which has the annotation applied to it - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/864c7c454dac61eb602674c4123d84e63f23d766/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L95 )

and so your `productRepository.findAll();` call will start a transaction, create a JPA session, run the query, close the session, close the transaction, which means that there is no longer any transaction / session open in which to perform the lazy-loading.

Therefore, your original attempt of

> i tried to put service methods in @Transactional annotation but that didn't work.

**IS** the correct thing to do.

You don't say *exactly* what you tried to do, and where, but there are a few things that could have gone wrong. Firstly, make sure you're adding a `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and not a `javax.transaction.Transactional` annotation.

Secondly (and the more likely problem in this scenario), you'll need to configure the annotation with *which* transaction manager the transaction should be bound to, otherwise it may use an existing / new transaction created against the master DB connection, not the tenant one.

In this case, I *think* that:

```
@Service
@Transactional(transactionManager = "tenantTransactionManager")
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
```

should work for you, and make all the methods of the service be bound to a transaction on the tenant DB connection.

**EDIT:** Answering a follow-up question:

> can you please also suggest a better way to inject my tenantTransactionManager in all my service classes, as I don't want to mention tenantTxnManger in all service classes if there is any better way to do it ?

Yes, sure. You can create a meta-annotation that applies multiple other annotations, so you could create:

```
    /**
     * Marks class as being a service operating on a single Tenant
     */
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Service
    @Transactional("tenantTransactionManager")
    public @interface TenantService {
    }
```

and then you can simply annotate your service classes with `@TenantService` instead of `@Service`:

```
@TenantService
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
```

Comment: bullseye....., you pointed out the issue accurately. Thanks @stevestorey.

Comment: can you please also suggest a better way to inject my tenantTransactionManager in all my service classes, I have close to 20-30 classes, I want one general code which can inject the required transaction manager in all the service classes.
Don't want to mention tenantTxnManger in all service classes if there is any better way to do it.

Comment: @ankursingh I've edited the answer above to explain how to create a meta-annotation to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> When access a lazy loaded model outside of the context of an open
> Hibernate session then this exception is arise.

You may use method level @Transactional annotation. Just do like this

```
public interface ProductService {
   @Transactional
   YourDto methodTobeImplemented(Params);
}

// And implementation service class no need to annotated.

@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
  
  @Override
  YourDto methodTobeImplemented(Params){
     return yourDto
  }
}
```