# New REST request in JHipster returning "Not Found - 404"

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, jhipster

### Error Description

Hey all,

I'm having trouble getting a response from my manually added controllers in a JHipster-based project. I scaffolded up the original project, and then hand-wrote my own services and controllers.

When I execute the call, the **error result I get from SoapUI** (which I am using for initial validation) is at the following url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSPYm.jpg

And if I look at my **Eclipse console error**, I see the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ToHB.jpg

### Controller

```
/**
 * GET  /courses/json -> get all the courses.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/json",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "application/json")
@Timed
public List<Course> getAll() {
    log.debug("REST request to get all Courses");
    return courseService.findAllCourses();
}
```

### Service

```
package com.testapp.myapp.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.testapp.myapp.domain.Course;
import com.testapp.myapp.repository.CourseRepository;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CourseServiceImpl implements CourseService {

    @Autowired
    CourseRepository courseRepository;

    public long countAllCourses() {
        return courseRepository.count();
    }

    public void deleteCourse(Course course) {
        courseRepository.delete(course);
    }

    public Course findCourse(Integer id) {
        return courseRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public List<Course> findAllCourses() {
        return courseRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Course> findCourseEntries(int firstResult, int maxResults) {
        return courseRepository.findAll(new org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest(firstResult / maxResults, maxResults)).getContent();
    }

    public void saveCourse(Course course) {
        courseRepository.save(course);
    }

    public Course updateCourse(Course course) {
        return courseRepository.save(course);
    }
}
```

What is confusing about this is that I ran the query provided by hibernate directly against my DB, and it returns the record set just fine. **Is it possible that the service is being blocked due to some security or authentication constraint auto-loaded by JHipster?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A few issues existed, all related to migrating from Roo into JHipster:

1. I had built my new Controller class with org.sprinframework.stereotype.Controller's **@Controller** annotation, rather than **@RestController**... The original controller annotation was scaffolded up by Spring Roo (which is highly effective at generating services from an existing DB using their DBRE addon, I might add).
2. After switching over to @RestController, I ran into the second hurdle, which I had originally expected as a JHipster implementation : **the service was being blocked due to authentication constraints**.

   - This was fixed by going into `com.[projectname].config` and updating the `SecurityConfiguration.java` file, exposing specifically the APIs that I wanted.
3. Then, I had to make sure Hibernate was getting the full collection of the objects being requested (I had a lot of complex relational entities being built by Roo)... **failed to lazily initialize a collection of role**...

   - In the Domain entity, change your @OneToMany annotation as follows:

     - `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "courseId", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)`
     - Source of answer: [Solve "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746499/how-to-resolve-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-exception)

Voila! Functioning, secure-able JSON-based APIs, fully reverse engineered from an existing Postgresql DB, loaded into a prescaffolded Angular front-end.