# JPA one-to many update fails

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
public class Post {

private Set<Comment> comments = new LinkedHashSet<Comment>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "businessunit", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<Comment> getComments() {
  return comments;
}
} 

@Entity
public class Comment {

private Post Post;
private BUnit bUnit;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "POST_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
public Post getPost() {
    return post;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "BU_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
public BUnit getBUnit() {
    return bUnit;
}
}
```

I have a Parent class containing Set of children. Add operation works fine as I add the comment's to Set and when I save the parent, children are saved too.

For update operation, I will be having an existing comment and new comment. I update the modified_by field for the existing comment and for the new comment I set its desired fields. Next I clear the set and add all the comments(new and existing one) so as I do not get all-delete-orphan error.

```
post.getComments().clear();
post.getComments().addAll(newComments);
dao.update(post);
```

Update throws exception org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:

Any ideas how to fix this problem for update where the child elements will contain a new and existing element.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your `mappedBy = "businessunit"` needs to refer to the property name on the other side, in this case, `post`.

If you're still seeing the exception, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746499/solve-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-exception).  (There are multiple reasons for this exception.)

Lastly, and a minor point, you don't need to explicitly label `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` since that's the default.  You can remove this to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks bphilipnyc for  pointing out, it is a editing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Update was executed under transaction and is working pretty fine. Outside of the transaction I was accessing the db model child objects to convert to the ui model. This was the reason for exception also I did not required to access the child elements so eventually I removed it.