# Spring Boot and fetchType=Lazy

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem with lazy initialization in my Spring Boot application. I have an entity with lazy field `Role`, and I they have `LazyInitializationException` in My Spring Security (`UserDetailsService`) method, but in controller it's ok.
Can you explaine to me how Spring Boot works with `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` ? Why it does not work Spring Security `UserDetailsService` and work in controller methods?
I did not find any guide about this. Thanks!

Spring Boot :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

An Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Users {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "Users_Role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
}
```

My Service:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)//does not matter
 public Users getUserByLogin(String login) {
        return usersRepository.findOneByLogin(login);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Users getUserByLoginWithRoles(String login) {
        Users oneByLogin = usersRepository.findOneByLogin(login);
        logger.debug("User was initialize with Roles: " + oneByLogin.getRoles().size()); // force initialize of roles and it works!
        return oneByLogin;
    }

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)//does not matter
    public Users testGetUser() {
        Users oneByLogin = usersRepository.getOne(1L);
        return oneByLogin;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)//does not matter
    public Users testFindUser() {
        Users oneByLogin = usersRepository.findOne(1L);
        return oneByLogin;
    }
```

And I have Spring Security UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
    public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private Services services;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user;
        Users userFetchedViaGet = services.testGetUser();
        Users userFetchedViaCustomMethod = services.getUserByLogin(login);
        Users userFetchedViaFind = services.testFindUser();
        Users userFetchedWithRoles = services.getUserByLoginWithRoles(login);
        try {
            userFetchedViaGet.getRoles().add(new Role("test"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();//LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: , could not initialize proxy - no Session
        }
        try {
            userFetchedViaCustomMethod.getRoles().add(new Role("test"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();//LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: , could not initialize proxy - no Session
        }
        try {
            userFetchedViaFind.getRoles().add(new Role("test")); //LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: , could not initialize proxy - no Session
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //some code
        }
    }
```

And My Controller (All methods works! But there is have to excpetion happen, because there is no session and Lazy fetch type):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() {      
        Users userFetchedViaGet = services.testGetUser();
        Users userFetchedViaCustomMethod = services.getUserByLogin("ADMIN");
        Users userFetchedViaFind = services.testFindUser();
        Users userFetchedWithRoles = services.getUserByLoginWithRoles("ADMIN");
        try {
            userFetchedViaGet.getRoles().add(new Role("test"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            userFetchedViaCustomMethod.getRoles().add(new Role("test"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            userFetchedViaFind.getRoles().add(new Role("test"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //some code
    }
```

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746499/solve-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-exception

Comment: Hello! That post doesn't have anything in common with my question.

Comment: Could you manage to solve this? I'm actually having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you need a transaction wrapping the entire thing - over your facade - the test() method for this to work, but this isn't really a good practice.

the way to go is to have your service wrap the api method in a transaction, and return an object that is fully loaded - with all child nodes. this object can be a simple bean that is constructed from the Users class,
a hashmap built from the objects or even a string like you wanted to return from the rest call.

Comment: Hello! Spring Data Jpa wrapping methods like testGetUser() in transaction readOnly=true by default. And I did it in method getUserByLoginWithRoles. Why the same methods like "testGetUser" doesn't work in Security class and work in controller? And why in controller I don't receive Lazy exception with Spring Boot? Why Spring Boot initialized my lazy collections? How Spring Boot does it?

Comment: hi. the thing is that the transaction ends right after using the spring data method, since you're using a lazy fetch between the User and the Role entities, the spring data method would only fetch the user without its roles. if wrapped in a larger transaction context it should be possible to traverse the user-role graph and fetch all roles from the database. you can obviously change the lazy fetch to eager if possible in this case, or write a simple hql query that forces fetching this join if you don't want to make this eager.