# Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role no Session 2 many-to-many relationships

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

I have for example i have project with this entities : `Category`, `Author` , `Book` ,`book_language` and `publisher`.

`Book` has Many-to-Many relations with `Category` and `Author`, and Many-to-One with `book_language` and `publisher`.

i need to update values in already created object:
Controller code:

```
public String update(@PathVariable int id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("book",bookService.readOne(id));
    return show(model);
```

Controller calls service method, which calls DAO method.
DAO method with query:

```
 @Query("SELECT b from Book b LEFT join fetch b.book_language left join fetch b.publisher " +
        "left join fetch b.categories where b.id = ?1")
Book readOne(int id);
```

And there is problem: i can't join fetch 2 many-to-many relations, but i need to, because i had `Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role no Session` exception.

So my question is: how should i correctly load these entities?

UPD:
[Solve "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746499/solve-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-exception)
This question is about one MtM relation, and my is about 2 or more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746499/solve-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-exception)

Comment: @OldProgrammer That isn't exactly the same.  That is only for the case of 1 collection, this question is specific to how to handle multiple collections simultaneously.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, yea, my question is about multiple collections. as i know, you can't join fetch 2+ collections