# Wildfly - how to enable transactions to enable lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, wildfly

I have User and Post entities with a unidirectional relationship. I am getting `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:` exception when I try to get all posts from a specific user.

According to these SO [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746499/solve-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-exception), the optimal way to handle this is to use `@Transactional` annotation for the service method/class. Placing annotations does not work for me. I am using Wildfly server, Hibernate, MySQL, and Java EE MVC web framework.

How do I make it work, i.e. get the posts from a user? I managed to do it via eager loading, but this is not recommended for performance reasons.

```
@Transactional
public class UserService {

    private List<User> users;
    private Set<Post> posts;


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my-pu")
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<User> getUsers() {

        String qlQuery = "SELECT u FROM User u";
        Query query = em.createQuery(qlQuery);
        users = query.getResultList();

        return users;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Set<Post> getUserPosts(Long userId) {

            String qlQuery = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = :userId";
            Query query = em.createQuery(qlQuery);
            query.setParameter("userId", userId);
            User user = (User) query.getSingleResult();

            posts = user.getPosts();

        return posts;
    }
}
```

This is my Service method.

```
@Path("users")
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    private Models models;

    @Inject
    private UserService service;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    @View("showUsers.ftl")
    public void users() {

        List<User> users = service.getUsers();

        models.put("users", users);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("text/html")
    @View("showUserPosts.ftl")    
    public void getPosts(@PathParam("id") Long userId) {

        System.out.println("here am i");

        Set<Post> posts = service.getUserPosts(userId);

        models.put("posts", posts);
    }
}
```

This is my controller.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
            <persistence-unit name="my-pu" transaction-type="JPA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useSSL=false"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="testuser"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test623"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect.storage_engine" value="innodb"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                      value="drop-and-create"/>      
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
                      value="META-INF/sql/data.sql" />        
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

An this is my persistence unit.

Error message:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.zetcode.model.User.posts, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:195)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:539)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:461)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:231)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:361)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:217)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
```

Comment: Why does your method query for an `User`, when it should be querying the posts? It's really convoluted to load a `User`, then get its posts and throw away the user. You should do a `SELECT p FROM Post p ...` or `SELECT u.posts FROM User u ...` instead.

Comment: Thanks, noted. It simply was more straightforward for me.

Comment: What's after `role:` in the error message you posted?

Comment: It's `com.zetcode.model.User.posts, could not initialize proxy - no Session` I have appended a stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an uninitialized collection proxy out of session boundaries (demarcated by the transaction in this case).

You can initialize the proxy by calling `Hibernate.initialize(posts)` or by just calling `posts.size()` before returning it (the first approach more clearly describes the intent imo).

An alternative that I use most often is to utilize DTOs, so that I don't have to deal with detached objects, but also because of the ability to tailor presentation objects (and web service responses in general) to the exact needs of clients using them. Also that way the domain model (Hibernate entities) is decoupled from the presentation logic, allowing the two to evolve independently.

Other alternatives include Open Session in View (anti-?) pattern and `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` property, but they are less flexible and have their own pros and cons.

Comment: The issue is resolved, this has been recognized as a bug and is resolved by Hibernate, there is a pull request and should be part of Hibernate 5.4.1. See Jira issue 13191 - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13191

Comment: Workaround for earlier version Hibernate, add hibernate.jpa.compliance.proxy=false