# How to properly manage session in Hibernate while dealing with OneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-session

I have these two classes with OneToMany relationship :

**Post.java :**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
private List<Comment> comments;
```

**Comment.java :**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idPost")
private Post post;
```

I am trying to get posts with their comments posted after some date. This is my method :

```
@Override
public List<Post> findPostsWithCommentsAfterYesterday() {
    List<Post> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        session.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
         Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Post.class);
        result = (List<Post>) criteria.createAlias("comments", "cms")
                .add(Restrictions.gt("cms.date", yesterday)).list();
        session.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit(); 
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    //
    return result;
}
```

The list returns corresponding comments but with this exception :

```
 org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.farouk.Post.comments, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:358)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:350)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:343)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:249)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:45)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
```

**no session or session was closed ?**

I know i am closing the session but after getting the list.

So what's the best practice when dealing with such situations ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11746720/10198003). It was about the fact that collections use lazy loading by default which i had to change to EAGER to get all comments.