# Call data of one to many relationship implemented with join table (3 tables)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp, jpa

I am working on a web application in java using Spring MVC and Hibernate as Frameworks.

I need to write javascript code in JSP where I need to call data from another table that is connected to the main table with a 3rd table to keep the one-to-many implementation.

Here I have the main table `tblDiscipline`, a second table `tblCompetenteProf`
and the join table `tblCompetenteProfDisciplina` and I want to obtain the list of `competenteProf` where `idDisciplina = x`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<td class="font-weight-bold">6.1</td>
            <td class="font-weight-bold">Competențe profesionale</td>
                <td>${disciplina.tblcompetenteprofdisciplinasByIdDisciplin}</td>
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE tblDiscipline
(
    idDisciplina   INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    idUniversitate INT                            NOT NULL,
    idFacultate    INT                            NOT NULL,
    idDomeniu      INT                            NOT NULL,
    idDepartament  INT                            NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE tblCompetenteProf
(
    idCompetentaProf  INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    codCompetentaProf VARCHAR(3),
    competentaProf    LONGTEXT
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE tblCompetenteProfDisciplina
(
    idCompetentaProfDisciplina INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    idCompetentaProf           INT                            NOT NULL,
    idDisciplina               INT                            NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (idDisciplina)
        REFERENCES tblDiscipline (idDisciplina) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (idCompetentaProf)
        REFERENCES tblCompetenteProf (idCompetentaProf) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

My entity classes look like this

TblDiscipline:

```java
@Entity
@Audited
package com.pages.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

@Entity
@Audited
public class Tbldiscipline {
    private int idDisciplina;
    private int idUniversitate;
    private int idFacultate;
    private int idDomeniu;
    private int idDepartament;
    private Collection<Tblcompetenteprofdisciplina>tblcompetenteprofdisciplinasByIdDisciplina;
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idDisciplina", nullable = false)
    public int getIdDisciplina() {
        return idDisciplina;
    }

    public void setIdDisciplina(int idDisciplina) {
        this.idDisciplina = idDisciplina;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "idUniversitate", nullable = true)
    public int getIdUniversitate() {
        return idUniversitate;
    }

    public void setIdUniversitate(int idUniversitate) {
        this.idUniversitate = idUniversitate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "idFacultate", nullable = true)
    public int getIdFacultate() {
        return idFacultate;
    }

    public void setIdFacultate(int idFacultate) {
        this.idFacultate = idFacultate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "idDomeniu", nullable = true)
    public int getIdDomeniu() {
        return idDomeniu;
    }

    public void setIdDomeniu(int idDomeniu) {
        this.idDomeniu = idDomeniu;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "idDepartament", nullable = true)
    public int getIdDepartament() {
        return idDepartament;
    }

    public void setIdDepartament(int idDepartament) {
        this.idDepartament = idDepartament;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tbldisciplineByIdDisciplina")
    public Collection<Tblcompetenteprofdisciplina> getTblcompetenteprofdisciplinasByIdDisciplina() {
        return tblcompetenteprofdisciplinasByIdDisciplina;
    }
```

TblCompetenteProfDisciplina:

```java
    private int idCompetentaProfDisciplina;
        private int idCompetentaProf;
        private int idDisciplina;
        private Tblcompetenteprof tblcompetenteprofByIdCompetentaProf;
        private Tbldiscipline tbldisciplineByIdDisciplina;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "idCompetentaProfDisciplina", nullable = false)
        public int getIdCompetentaProfDisciplina() {
            return idCompetentaProfDisciplina;
        }

        public void setIdCompetentaProfDisciplina(int idCompetentaProfDisciplina) {
            this.idCompetentaProfDisciplina = idCompetentaProfDisciplina;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "idCompetentaProf", nullable = false)
        public int getIdCompetentaProf() {
            return idCompetentaProf;
        }

        public void setIdCompetentaProf(int idCompetentaProf) {
            this.idCompetentaProf = idCompetentaProf;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "idDisciplina", nullable = false)
        public int getIdDisciplina() {
            return idDisciplina;
        }

        public void setIdDisciplina(int idDisciplina) {
            this.idDisciplina = idDisciplina;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Tblcompetenteprofdisciplina that = (Tblcompetenteprofdisciplina) o;
            return idCompetentaProfDisciplina == that.idCompetentaProfDisciplina &&
                    idCompetentaProf == that.idCompetentaProf &&
                    idDisciplina == that.idDisciplina;
        }
            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name = "idCompetentaProf", referencedColumnName = "idCompetentaProf",
                    nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
            public Tblcompetenteprof getTblcompetenteprofByIdCompetentaProf() {
                return tblcompetenteprofByIdCompetentaProf;
            }

            public void setTblcompetenteprofByIdCompetentaProf(Tblcompetenteprof tblcompetenteprofByIdCompetentaProf) {
                this.tblcompetenteprofByIdCompetentaProf = tblcompetenteprofByIdCompetentaProf;
            }

            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name = "idDisciplina", referencedColumnName = "idDisciplina",
                    nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
            public Tbldiscipline getTbldisciplineByIdDisciplina() {
                return tbldisciplineByIdDisciplina;
            }

            public void setTbldisciplineByIdDisciplina(Tbldiscipline tbldisciplineByIdDisciplina) {
                this.tbldisciplineByIdDisciplina = tbldisciplineByIdDisciplina;
            }
```

To obtain a list of all Rows of `tblCompetenteProf` `WHERE idDisciplina = 1` (for instance).
`disciplina` is the attribute name defined in my controller:

```
@Controller
public class DisciplinaController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DisciplinaController.class);

    public DisciplinaController() {
        System.out.println("DisciplinaController()");
    }

    @Autowired
    private DisciplinaService disciplinaService;
    @Autowired
    private CompetentaProfService competentaProfService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/disciplina")
    public ModelAndView listDisciplina(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<Tbldiscipline> listDisciplina = disciplinaService.getAllDiscipline();
        model.addObject("listDisciplina", listDisciplina);
        model.setViewName("Disciplina");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newDisciplina", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newDisciplina(ModelAndView model){
        Tbldiscipline disciplina = new Tbldiscipline();
        model.addObject("disciplina", disciplina);
        model.setViewName("DisciplinaFormular");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveDisciplina", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveDisciplina(@ModelAttribute Tbldiscipline disciplina){
        if (disciplina.getIdDisciplina() == 0){
            disciplinaService.addDisciplina(disciplina);
        } else{
            disciplinaService.updateDisciplina(disciplina);
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/disciplina");
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteDisciplina", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteDisciplina(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int disciplinaid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idDisciplina"));
        disciplinaService.deleteDisciplina(disciplinaid);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/disciplina");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editDisciplina", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editDisciplina(HttpServletRequest request){
        int idDisciplina = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idDisciplina"));
        Tbldiscipline disciplina = disciplinaService.getDisciplina(idDisciplina);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("DisciplinaFormular");
        model.addObject("disciplina", disciplina);

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/viewDisciplina", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView updateDisciplina(HttpServletRequest request){
        int idDisciplina = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idDisciplina"));
        Tbldiscipline disciplina = disciplinaService.getDisciplina(idDisciplina);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("DisciplinaVizualizare");
        model.addObject("disciplina", disciplina);

        return model;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/viewPDF", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView viewPDF(@ModelAttribute DisciplineListContainer disciplineListContainer) throws Exception{
        List<Tbldiscipline> tbldisciplineList = disciplineListContainer.getTbldisciplines();
        return new ModelAndView("viewPDF", "Disciplina", tbldisciplineList);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView downloadExcel() {
        List<Tbldiscipline> listDisciplina = new ArrayList<Tbldiscipline>();
        return new ModelAndView("pdfView", "listDisciplina", listDisciplina);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPDFDisciplina", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView downloadDisciplina(HttpServletRequest request){
        int idDisciplina = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idDisciplina"));
        Tbldiscipline disciplina = disciplinaService.getDisciplina(idDisciplina);
        return new ModelAndView("pdfViewDisciplina", "disciplina", disciplina);
    }
```

````
My DisciplineView looks like this:

```javascript

    <c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <body>
        <form action="/viewDisciplina" method="get">
            <div align="center">
            <div class="container">

                <p style="padding-bottom: 50px"></p>

                <h1>
                    Disciplina: ${disciplina.denumireDisciplina}
                </h1>
            <h2>6.Competențe specifice acumulate</h2>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="font-weight-bold">6.1</td>
                    <td class="font-weight-bold">Competențe profesionale</td>
                    <td>${disciplina.tblcompetenteprofdisciplinasByIdDisciplina}</td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
````

This is the error that I am getting:

> HTTP ERROR 500 Problem accessing /viewDisciplina. Reason:
>
> ```
> Server Error Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page
> ```
>
> /WEB-INF/pages/DisciplinaVizualizare.jsp at line 253
>
> 250:              251:                 6.1 252:                 Competen?e profesionale 253:
>   ${disciplina.tblcompetenteprofdisciplinasByIdDisciplina} 254:
>    255:  256: <%--
>   ${disciplina.tblcompetenteprofdisciplinasByIdDisciplina.}--%>
>
> Stacktrace:   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:107)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:191)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role:
>   com.pages.model.Tbldiscipline.tblcompetenteprofdisciplinasByIdDisciplina,
>   could not initialize proxy - no Session   at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:576)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:215)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:143)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:526)
>     at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToString(ELSupport.java:426)
>     at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:446)    at
>   org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
>     at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:232)     at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.DisciplinaVizualizare_jsp._jspService(DisciplinaVizualizare_jsp.java:489)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     ... 47 more Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:
>   failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>   com.pages.model.Tbldiscipline.tblcompetenteprofdisciplinasByIdDisciplina,
>   could not initialize proxy - no Session   at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:576)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:215)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:143)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:526)
>     at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToString(ELSupport.java:426)
>     at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:446)    at
>   org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
>     at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:232)     at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.DisciplinaVizualizare_jsp._jspService(DisciplinaVizualizare_jsp.java:489)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:107)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:191)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

DisciplineController:

```java
I have no errors. What I am actually trying to do is to obtain something like:

        <tr>
            <td class="font-weight-bold">6.1</td>
            <td class="font-weight-bold">Competențe profesionale</td>
            <td>${disciplina.tblcompetenteprofdisciplinasByIdDisciplin}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: this is not javascript

Comment: Could you please fix the `Tbldiscipline` class? It doesn't seem to be valid. If it's possible, better post the whole classes, so it will be close to a reproducible example.

Comment: Please also post the error that you get. From the current post, I see, for instance, that your entity and db table names are distinct and you don't use `@Table(name = "dbTableName")` on the entity classes. It is also not clear whether you have `@Id` columns declared in the entiies.

Comment: @Maria Ok, this looks much better, although 1st class has superfluous annotations to it, and the 3rd class is not complete.

And don't forget to post and error that you're getting.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746499/how-to-solve-the-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-hibernate-ex) out .