# Adding Transactional to fix LazyInitializationException when fetching SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() doesnt work

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Springboot and I'm trying to fix the issue where I get an error when trying to reach `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` here:

My aim is to retrieve the `UserDetails` from the `OncePerRequestFilter` (once authenticated) and pass the UserId / UserDetails to the Controller so that I can retrieve the user's associated articles.

I tried adding @Transactional from `import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;` in several places but it doesn't seem to work.

`JwtAuthenticationFilter.java`

```
@Transactional
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/article")
public class ArticleController {

    private final ArticleService articleService;

    @Autowired
    public ArticleController(ArticleService articleService){
        this.articleService = articleService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Article> getArticleByUser()
            throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); // error here
        System.out.println(authentication);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
    };
```

The SecurityContextHolder's context is set here in a `OncePerRequestFilter` when the request flows in.

`ArticleController.java`

```
package com.codaholic.shop.config;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


    private JwtService jwtService;
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            // pass the req and res to the next filter
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUserName(jwt);
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails,
                    null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                    new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error log when curling the endpoint:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-01-15T08:18:13.532+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.codaholic.shop.models.security.user.User.articles: could not initialize proxy - no Session\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:635)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:615)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:136)\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:589)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)\n\tat com.codaholic.shop.models.security.user.User.toString(User.java:16)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:169)\n\tat org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken.toString(AbstractAuthenticationToken.java:177)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)\n\tat java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:1047)\n\tat com.codaholic.shop.controllers.ArticleController.getArticleByUser(ArticleController.java:42)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)\n\tat com.codaholic.shop.controllers.ArticleController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getArticleByUser(<generated>)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:289)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat com.codaholic.shop.config.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:59)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\n",
    "message": "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.codaholic.shop.models.security.user.User.articles: could not initialize proxy - no Session",
    "path": "/api/v1/article/"
}
```

Not sure if I am doing this correct. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Using `@Transactional` in controller layer is a bad practice, check this answer for more options on how to solve the lazyInitilizaion problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/11754441/2551236

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was to create a CustomUserDetails class to capture the details and then store it into the `authToken` like this:

`CustomUserDetails.java`

```
package com.codaholic.shop.models.security.user;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CustomUserDetails extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User{

    private final UUID userId;

    public CustomUserDetails(
            UUID userId, String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
    ) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public UUID getUserId(){
        return userId;
    }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter.java

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUserName(jwt);
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            CustomUserDetails userDetails = this.userService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);

            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails,
                    null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                    new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
```

and that solved my problem.